# how to scrape ajax post requested url using curl and php

Tags: php, ajax, curl, screen-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** ajax post requested url from last 3 hours.but not get success.

I try  this url
"https://example/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes%5B0%5D=3&deliveryTimes%5B1%5D=51&deliveryTimes%5B2%5D=55"

in browser but it show the error  **405 http verb not allowed**.

I try to find a code to scrape ajax post requested url for 3 hours not get any working code.

Please share any code or suitable link for this. any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: try using curl with options post and https off

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid url/uri : `https://example/api/`